# Strategy for providing (oh my zsh) git autocompletion on an alias associated to a script?

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use oh my zsh, with the git plugin, which provides autocompletion for the most common actions (for example, branch deletion).

I wanted to write an alias that deletes a local branch, and also the associate remote branch, while still getting autocompletion, however, when I associate an alias to a shell script, autocompletion doesn't work as intended.

For example, with this alias:

```
full_delete = !sh -c 'git branch -D $1 && git push origin :$1' -
```

the autocompletion lists the files, but *not* the branches.

Is there any way to provide branch autocompletion for an alias like this (or anyway, an strategy to fulfill the requirement)?

Comment: Note that shells, in general, are unaware of *Git* aliases (though you can teach them such things using completion scripts). Writing *shell functions*, as in [Josh Friedlander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73779054/1256452), is usually the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're doing here - it's an alias, but it has parameters? [Not a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34340688/6220759).

But if I understand what you're trying to do, then it's easily done with a function. Say your `.zshrc` contains this:

```
full_delete() {
    git branch -D "$1" && git push origin :"$1"
}
```

Then just tell `zsh` to give it git completions for `git-branch`:

```
compdef _git full_delete=git-branch
```

You don't need OMZ for any of this btw, it's part of native zsh completion.

Comment: I used the wrong terminology, I guess it's an "alias function" (an entry in the `[alias]` section of the `.gitconfig` file) :) I've applied your suggestion, and added `brfd = !full_delete` to such section, and it works!